# android app with different type of users

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i am developing a android app which basically has 3 type of users client, driver, admin so when user install app it will launch a activity for the selection of user type means 3 buttons on it client, driver or admin. when user select a type he/she will be pushed to that specific activity for example if he selects client then he will be pushed to ClientActivity. and when ever he launches the app after first time he will automatically pushed to ClientActivity. first activity that gives option for user selection will online display first time when app install. i already did this in my ios app with use of userdefaults to save a variable and retrieving it from phone memory. so i need suggestions how can i achieve this maybe a stupid question but i am new with android development. so any kind of help will be appreciated :)
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Shared preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref),
When the activity creates check a boolean value that saved in shared preference and based on the value u can use.

For declaration:

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); 
Editor editor = pref.edit();
```

to save value

```
editor.putInt("key_name", 0);
editor.commit();
```

to view the data

```
int value=pref.getInt("key_name", 0);
```

based on the value u can pass the specific intent.

Comment: i simply want to put a integer value in shared pref not a boolean. int will only hold values like  1 2 or 3. so will u please edit your ans according to a int variable!! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

android has `sharedprefereces` concept same as `userdefaults` in ios. You can use in application specific context or component level context. I suggest better application level context.This `shareprefereces` values can primitives, objects wont support. And these values will be available for you untill application is unistalled.